# Ubuntu 13.04 CMake and Qt4 and Qt5

Tags: ubuntu, qt4, qt5

I'm using the new Ubuntu 13.04 and installed qt via `apt-get install`. It seems that qt5 is installed now. A CMake Project using qt5 workes well.

I had the same code running on a machine with qt4 installed on ubuntu 12.04 and it worked well. But now I get the following Error: (Do not worry about the boost stuff, it comes from a Parent CMakeLists.txt)

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:619 (message):
  Could NOT find QtCore.  Check
  /home/simongroth/Projects/pgCrazyMachinesVR/src-build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log
  for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Views/LevelEditor/CMakeLists.txt:32 (FIND_PACKAGE)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:615 (message):
  /usr/bin/qmake-qt4 reported QT_INSTALL_LIBS as "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
  but QtCore could not be found there.  Qt is NOT installed correctly for the
  target build environment.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Views/LevelEditor/CMakeLists.txt:32 (FIND_PACKAGE)

-- Boost version: 1.49.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

This is my `CMakeLists.txt`. Does anyone have any idea how to use qt4 and qt5 at the same time on the new ubuntu? Thanks in advance.

```
FILE(GLOB COLLECTED_HDR_FILES *.hpp)
FILE(GLOB COLLECTED_SRC_FILES *.cpp)
FILE(GLOB COLLECTED_UI_FILES *.ui)
FILE(GLOB COLLECTED_RCS_FILES *.qrc)

SET( SRCS
${COLLECTED_SRC_FILES}
)

SET( HDRS
${COLLECTED_HDR_FILES}
)

SET( MOC_HDRS
${HDRS}
)

SET( UIS
${COLLECTED_UI_FILES}
)

SET( RCS
${COLLECTED_UI_FILES}
MainWindow.qrc
)

# enable warnings
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-Wall)

# this command finds Qt4 libraries and sets all required variables
# note that it's Qt4, not QT4 or qt4
FIND_PACKAGE(Qt4 REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenGL REQUIRED)

# by default only QtCore and QtGui modules are enabled
# other modules must be enabled like this:
SET(QT_USE_QTXML TRUE)
SET(QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE)

# add some useful macros and variables
# (QT_USE_FILE is a variable defined by FIND_PACKAGE( Qt4 ) that contains a path to CMake script)
INCLUDE( ${QT_USE_FILE} )

# this command will generate rules that will run rcc on all files from SAMPLE_RCS
# in result SAMPLE_RC_SRCS variable will contain paths to files produced by rcc
QT4_ADD_RESOURCES( RC_SRCS ${RCS} )

# this will run uic on .ui files:
QT4_WRAP_UI( UI_HDRS ${UIS} )

# and finally this will run moc:
QT4_WRAP_CPP( MOC_SRCS ${MOC_HDRS} ${UI_HDRS} )

# we need this to be able to include headers produced by uic in our code
# (CMAKE_BINARY_DIR holds a path to the build directory, while INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES() works just like INCLUDEPATH from qmake)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})

# here we instruct CMake to build executable from all of the source files
ADD_EXECUTABLE( LevelEditor ${HDRS} ${SRCS} ${MOC_SRCS} ${RC_SRCS} ${UI_HDRS} )

# last thing we have to do is to tell CMake what libraries our executable needs,
# luckily FIND_PACKAGE prepared QT_LIBRARIES variable for us:
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( LevelEditor ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adding qt5 to CMakeLists.txt is different from qt4, you can find many useful link like [this](http://www.kdab.com/using-cmake-with-qt-5/), by the way version of my ubuntu is 12.04 and i installed the qt without apt-get, i use this format to find qt in my cmakelists.txt :

```
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDES}
/opt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/gcc/include/QtGui
/opt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/gcc/include/QtCore
/opt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/gcc/include/QtNetwork
/opt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/gcc/include/QtWidgets
/opt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/gcc/include/QtWebKit
/opt/Qt5.0.5/5.0.5/gcc/include/QtScript
)

add_definitions(${Qt5Widgets_DEFINITIONS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${Qt5Widgets_EXECUTABLE_COMPILE_FLAGS} -I/opt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2`    /gcc/include -L/opt/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/gcc/lib -DQT5")`
```

you should replace address of your header files with my address and also you should use target_link_libraries in this way:

```
target_link_libraries(LevelEditor ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${Qt5Widgets_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: The OP asked about Qt5 installed via `apt-get` in Ubuntu, not by hand.

Comment: The include_directories snippet here is bizarre. See http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-qt.7.html which now documents finding and using Qt 4 and 5. Prior to CMake 3.0 you may get conflicts.